# For loop in a class definition javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Recently I ran into some code that basically looks like :

```
class A {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.a = {};
  }

  for(x, y) {
   ...

    return {
      async check(id) {
        ... 
      }
   };
  }
...more method definitions in the class
}
```

I'm wondering how its possible to put a for loop inside a class definition . I can see that it is returning a function, but does this mean that the returned function becomes a member function for the class?

Comment: That's not a for-loop, it's merely a method (property) named `for`. It uses none of the standard loop syntax (`for (;;)` or `for (.. in ..)`) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a for loop, it's a method named 'for'.

More or less equivalent to

```
A.prototype.for = function for( x, y ) {
    ...
    return {
      async check(id) {
        ... 
      }
   };
}
```